# How to reference a cell in the same column in a loop, vba

Tags: vba

I need to loop through all the cells in an array, then input a set of values if the conditions are met. Trouble is that I do not know how to reference the cell with my current code.

I will need to compare all cell values against today's date. If today's date equals a particular cell value. Insert certain wordings into row 50 in the same column as the cell.

```
Sub Macro 1

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("CDR")

        For Each c In ws.Range("$G$13:$T$40")
            If c.Value = ws.Range("G6") Then ______
        Next c

End Sub
```

If for example the date in cell `A3` is today's date (`G6`), insert "yes" in cell `A50`.

Comment: Do you not want to use something like: `ws.Cells(50, c.Column).Value = "Yes"` when the condition is met?

Comment: You are already referencing your cell `c.Value = ws.Range("G6")` ... just reuse the same principle after `then`.